# Random Image Position in programming website?

Tags: html, css, image, random, marquee

I want to make it so I have "enemies" spawn in the background (not THE background, just images on top of it) of a particular webpage at random heights and scroll across the screen. Right now I have something like:

```
<script>
    function numberRandomizer(){
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 300); //random number between 300 and 800
      return x;
    }
  </script>
```

I've tried 2 methods to applying this random variable X to the images that loop by scrolling on screen:

1) Doing what I thought would work and editing each image to get a random value for top and left

```
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="numberRandomizer()"><img src="/aboutme/enemy.png" width="120" height="80" top="numberRandomizer()" left="numberRandomizer()"/><p></marquee>
```

2) Even though as far as I know it would make all enemies have the same position, try out CSS styling to make the placement random just to see if it would work:

```
 <style>
    img {
      top: numberRandomizer();
      left: numberRandomizer();
    }
  </style>
```

Neither style works in setting a random value for the image location, am I getting a minor thing wrong or going about this completely the wrong way?

As a bonus question: Is it possible to set marquee to go a random direction per image?

Comment: You can't mix javascript and css like that

Comment: You need to use javascript to get this img tag and then change its top and left there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the same thing using plain javascript too

html:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" id="elem">Test</marquee>
<br/>
<button id="butR">Right</button>
<button id="butL">Left</button>

<div class="area">
<div id="enemy"></div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById('butR').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('elem').setAttribute("direction", "right");   
});

document.getElementById('butL').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('elem').setAttribute("direction", "left");   
});

function numberRandomizer(){
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 50); //random number between 50 and 300
  return x;
}


document.getElementById('enemy').style.top = numberRandomizer() + 'px';
document.getElementById('enemy').style.left = numberRandomizer() + 'px';
```

I've added also a way to change marque direction. Take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/oyv324z9/

Comment: I sort of understand what is going on here, but when trying to apply a ID to my image that is marquee-ing, the image never changes orientation:

  `<body>
  <script>
    function numberRandomizer(){
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 300); //random number between 300 and 800
      return x;
    }
    document.getElementById("enemy").style.top = numberRandomizer() + 'px';
  </script>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5"><img id="enemy" src="/aboutme/enemy.png"/></marquee>`

My current body. Sorry if I'm doing something obviously wrong, new to webdev

Comment: You should be changing direction of the marquee element not the image itself: https://jsfiddle.net/oyv324z9/5/

Comment: Sorry, when I meant that the orientation didn't change, I meant that the image never moves or down by numberRandomizer()'s X value and stays at the top of the screen.

Comment: As you have your image inside marquee you will need to change style of this element

Comment: Worked like a charm, just had to do some bugfixing. Another problem I had was executing the style editors without running another function, but I managed to work around it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a couple people said, you can't mix JS and CSS. If you are using jQuery though, this is pretty simple. Basically, you want to use jQuery to add CSS styles to the `img`. Something like this.

```
//your trigger here and then..
$( "#your_img_id" ).css( "left", function(index) {
  return index * numberRandomizer() ;
});
$( "#your_img_id" ).css( "right", function(index) {
  return index * numberRandomizer() ;
});
```

Comment: It seems like OP doesn't know much of jQuery, perhaps a more detailed explanation would clear the confusion of OP's?